# How does PHP Socket works in term of structure

Tags: php, sockets

I just curious about how php socket work in term of its structure? I had tried to create a server socket with port 80 which is occupied by my Web server and it run perfectly without error. Is it keeping its own port list instead of using the system port? I hope can get more explanation and clarification.

Thank you for your explanation.

Comment: Have you looked into the documented examples here? http://php.net/manual/en/sockets.examples.php

Comment: Include your actual code, if you have questions about its behaviour. Custom tutoring is off-topic. And your remembrance of what happened with an already bound port 80 seems implausible.